# check multiple variables binding classes on vuejs

Tags: javascript, class, vuejs2

i want a specific class to be applied to a DOM element if the var1 OR the var2 are true.

```
<div :class="{classToBeApplied: var1 [i don't know how to add the var2 here]}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what i was looking for can be achieved with pipes this way: `<div :class="{classToBeApplied: var1 || var2}"></div>`
, this way the classToBeApplied class will be applied wether the var1 OR the var2 are true.

Comment: <div :class="{classToBeApplied: var1 || var2}"></div>
You can use some js expressions here.